# javascript cloneNode deep but change parent nodeType/nodeName

Tags: javascript, clone, dom4

How to cloneNode and then convert that nodeName, cuz I want the attributes copied and children deeply (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.cloneNode)

so like: i have a span with a bunch of attributes and children. i want the same thing but i want it a div

much thanks

after i manage to clone and change to div i want to replace the span with it. also is there a way to clone all event listeners on it?

Comment: No, you cannot clone event listeners. The nodeName is immutable, so you will need to create a new element and copy all child nodes to "change" the nodeName. But what do you need that for? Isn't `<span style="display:block;">` enough?

Comment: Hi Bergi thank for the reply. On GitHub theres no Fork button on your own gists. SO I was adding one in, the way i do it is by cloning the "star" button and then changing to have the fork href.
i accomplished this clone with jquery but i wanted to do with native functions. please see the gist (https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8794639) at line 46 where i accomplish this clone with jquery. i turn it from a span to a "A" because its orignally a span when count is 0. but href on span wont be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following doesn't handle text children which are *directly* under the original span element, but otherwise should work fine.

```
    mutantClone = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i=0; i<original.childNodes.length; i++){
        var child = original.childNodes[i];
        var childClone = child.cloneNode(true);
        mutantClone.appendChild(childClone);
    }
```